# Is a relative clause always a permission for "the" article to be used before its antecedent?

Tags: definite-articles, relative-clauses

I have noticed that most often *a relative pronoun* such as who, which, etc. is used to further inform the reader about its preceding noun or noun phrase, e.g.

> 1-Do you know the girl who is talking to Tom?[1]
>   2. I told you about the woman who lives next door.[2]
>   3. The man who did this is the brother of our neighbour, Mr. Smith. [3]

In both statements above, *the* precedes the noun, i.e.   *girl* and *woman*, respectively. But, my question is:
**Are relative clauses always a justification for using the definite article "the" before their antecedent?**
For instance, in the following statement, *individuals* is not specifically known of in the context, and thus the only introduction for that comes in its relative clause *who had not taken part...*. Has *the* been used correctly here? Or should it be omitted?

> ... and providing questionnaires to the individuals who had not taken part in the coordination meeting of Khuzestan soccer referees

References:
-1 and 2, http://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/relative-clauses
-3, Tipping, L., Matriculation English Grammar, 1967

Comment: When the noun is plural, I think _the_ becomes optional, but there's a slightly different connotation. _I told you about people who eat seafood._

Answer (score 3):

The usage of "the" usually pertains to nouns and/or subjects which are specific or definite. 
In the sentence *"... and providing questionnaires to the individuals who had not taken part in the coordination meeting of Khuzestan soccer referees"*, using "the" implies that there was a specific group of individuals who had not taken part. If "the" was left out the sentence would have been a general statement referring to unspecified individuals.